# ROS Smach State Machine: Using single subscriber for transition in multiple states

Tags: python, state, ros, state-machine, rospy

I have a ROS subscriber that is looking at a message which is mostly False and periodically True, this is essentially suppose to simulate a button press.

I want to transition from IDLE -> ACTIVE if I see a True and again from ACTIVE -> COMPLETE when a True is seen again.

I tried implementing the first two states but I'm not sure how to initialize a subscriber once and use the data from the subscriber within two states for transitioning in both states. Is there a best practice for this?

I've only added the first two states so far for testing purposes but would ultimately need the third.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import smach
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
import numpy as np


class Idle(smach.State):  # Define a state and outcomes
    def __init__(self):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['start', 'wait'])

    def execute(self, userdata):
        rospy.loginfo('Idle')
        # if toggled
        #     return 'start'
        # return 'wait'


class Active(smach.State):   # Define a state and outcomes
    def __init__(self):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['complete'])


    def execute(self, userdata):
        rospy.loginfo('Active')
        return 'complete'


def init_sm(events):
    # create SMACH state machine
    sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['finished'])
    sm.set_initial_state(['IDLE'])

    with sm:  # This opens sm container for adding states:
        smach.StateMachine.add('IDLE', Idle(events),  # Add state and transition
                transitions={'start':'ACTIVE', 'wait' : 'IDLE'})

        smach.StateMachine.add('ACTIVE', Active(),    # Add state and transition
                transitions={'complete':'finished'})

    return sm


# ROS MESSAGE CALLBACKS
def button_cb(msg):
  # NOTE: I want to be able to somehow save a transition variable used in both states here
  print(msg.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # events = Events()
    rospy.init_node('node')
    rospy.sleep(0.5)

    rospy.Subscriber("/button", Bool, button_cb)

    sm = init_sm() # Create state machine
    outcome = sm.execute()   # Execute state machine
    rospy.spin()
```

Comment: That's a good question. Unfortunately I don't have a good answer. I would create subscriber for each state and update a flag in callback which is checked in a loop in execute(). And when the flag is true return outcome from execute(). Just don't make infinite loop without any delay because it will eat CPU adding rate.sleep() for 10Hz or whatever speed you need will be enough. It is okay to block execute() as long as you want. Once you return from this execute(), the current state is finished. There may be better method tho